# Trying to get a basic PHP-based app with a MySQL database running, having issues with the database port in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm making a very basic web app with PHP and a MySQL database. I am able to get Apache running on the default ports 80,443, but when I try to connect to my database using the default port 3306, XAMPP reports the following error:

```
Status change detected: stopped
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:40:02 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've tried switching the port to 3307 and that allows me to connect, but it can no longer find the database I'm trying to connect to. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: Random guess: you're running something else on port 3306 already.

Comment: Possibly, but I'm not sure what it is. It seems like changing the port for my database is the solution, but when I tried changing the port to 3307 before, it could connect but it couldn't find my database anymore. Is there a better port to use instead, or is there a way to make my database accessible at port 3307?

Comment: I think it'd be a better idea to find out what's running on 3306 if mysql isn't.

Comment: You were right. The answer was that the MySQL Workbench service was already running in the background on port 3306. I started Apache and left MySQL off in XAMPP and my application is now able to connect to MySQL workbench and is running as it should.